# Требует ли celery предварительного создания очередей

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

Требует ли celery обязательного предварительного создания очередей?
Или можно запускать её и без них (для теста запуска сервиса).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы в конфигурации celery нужно указать, какой брокер использовать, т.е. тип брокера и адрес.

`celery` сама позаботится обо всем, включая создание очередей.

Если вопрос про то, сможет ли celery работать без брокера вообще, то ответ - нет, не сможет.